# angular service calls takes time only sometimes

Tags: performance, angular8, angular-services, page-load-time, web-performance

I have an web app, front end in  angular and backend .Net Web API.

There are times when the application becomes slow and during that time I have seen that some of the service calls take longer, as shown in the network capture in the chrome tool. If I call the same services directly using postman or jmeter they are very fast, but through UI it takes time.
[Update] The slow services are random. Next time when it is ran, there are other services that takes time. May not be the ones those were found slower earlier.

This happens sometimes not always. When the app performs fine, all services respond in milli seconds and so continue to do so when directly called as well.

Any pointer.

[image]

[image: memory pic]

Comment: You want to speed up process or add any pointer/loader until its response has  received ?

Comment: speed up the process. the loader is there. I want to fins why calls through angular takes time but not direct API calls.

Comment: Delay occurs from your `API` not `Angular` . May be in few calls you result involves multiple tables that can cause delay .

Comment: no. I used j-meter and ran same quires and API responds in mill seconds.

Comment: Then you should debug it in which situations it takes more time than as expected then improve that chunk of code

Comment: I added an update. There is no fixed set of calls that takes time. It changes when the page is refreshed.